# Add a custom field on a sharepoint page into a custom content type

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I have create some site columns in my sharepoint page. I tried to add it to my content type create by code but it got exception : the field is deleted or not exist. 
My question is can I add a field create on a sharepoint page into a content type by code? If yes, how can I do it?

*Note: I know there is a way to add a custome field (create by code) to content-type through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add site column to a content type, we can use PnP powershell to achieve it.

[Add-PnPFieldToContentType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/add-pnpfieldtocontenttype?view=sharepoint-ps)

**Example**:

```
Add-PnPFieldToContentType -Field "Project_Name" -ContentType "Project Document"
```